# faye rails duplicate messages after definining the faye.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, faye

I have followed the faye railscast and I have a working chat app. My problem is that chrome gives a 404 error,  javascripts/defaults.js    not found. I found that the problem was in my application layout:

```
   <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults, "http://myip/faye/faye.js" %>
```

I changed that with:

```
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "http://myip/faye/faye.js" %>
```

and the error disappeared but when I am sending through my form the message it creates and broadcasts a duplicate  record of the message.

If more information needed plz ask, I am not sure which part of my code to include in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Faye is a obsolete. Try to use native mechanism - SSE (server set events). It is a best technique for Rails 4 and all modern clients.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I understand but I use unicorn for my app.. isn't that a problem for asynchronous events?

Comment: Use puma. It is a faster and simple than are unicorn. Puma have full sse support.

Comment: Good info, but "change your webserver and use a different mechanism" is the only solution?  I inherited code with faye.js in it, and need to get it working asap.  After that, I can lobby the client for the dev-time to improve their system.

Comment: Migrate to puma is so simple. Would you see my gist (https://gist.github.com/9719095) puma config files?